# Paste gif image into NSPasteboard

Tags: macos, swift

I am developing osx application. I want to paste an **Gif** image into pasteboard. How can I do that?

What I have is

- NSImage
- NSPasteboard

What I want to do is to paste that image into pasteboard. I am able to paste **PNG** image but what I need is to paste **GIF** image.

---

My existing code

```
let imageURL = imageObject.imageURL!
let fileName = imageURL.lastPathComponent
var saveURL = NSURL(string: "file://" + NSTemporaryDirectory())
saveURL = saveURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName!)
// I have data now
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)

pasteboard.declareTypes([NSTIFFPboardType], owner: nil)
pasteboard.setData(data!, forType: "com.compuserve.gif")
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did your results differ from what you expected? What does your working PNG code look like?

Answer (score 1):

About 10 years ago same one asked [How do I put a GIF onto an NSPasteboard?](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2005/Nov/msg01787.html)
in an Apple discussion group and here is my answer. Although  10 years old and the NSPasteboard methods changed since that time  my answer still works. I confess: my advice is a bit dirty.

Comment: I tried that before and somehow it didn't work for me. GIF file is converted into PNG file for some reason.

Comment: can you write it in Swift here please?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it working after spending 6 hours searching online.

Basically I have to download the image file and paste it as a filename.

```
        let imageURL = imageObject.imageURL!
        let fileName = imageURL.lastPathComponent
        var saveURL = NSURL(string: "file://" + NSTemporaryDirectory())
        saveURL = saveURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName!)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)
        data?.writeToURL(saveURL!, atomically: true)

        pasteboard.declareTypes([NSFilenamesPboardType], owner: nil)
        pasteboard.writeObjects([saveURL!])
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using the following code:

```
let pb = NSPasteboard.general
do {
  let fileType = try NSWorkspace.shared.type(ofFile: localPath.path)
  let pasteboardType = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.init(fileType)
  pb.declareTypes([pasteboardType], owner: nil)
  pb.writeObjects([localPath as NSURL])
} catch {
  return
}
```