# Animated GIF into NSPasteboard

Tags: swift, cocoa, animated-gif, nspasteboard

Trying to copy a local animated `.gif` file into `NSPasteboard`. The operation appears to complete successfully however, only the first frame of the `.gif` is present when pasted.

```
let filePath = "file:///Users/me/Documents/test.gif"
let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pasteboard.clearContents()
pasteboard.declareTypes([NSFilenamesPboardType], owner: nil)
pasteboard.writeObjects([fileUrl])
```

What I have so far is based mainly off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616393/2753206) post, but I'm guessing the author's `.gif` wasn't animated and thats why it worked for them?